How to write iterable class with sentinel to use it in find_if?
I have C++ code written around March 2023. It compiled fine back then. Now, I have to make a few changes to it, but it doesn't compile anymore. The used language standard was C++20. I don't remember what version of VS was used then. That was definitely updated to the latest one.
Now I get "error C3889: call to object of class type 'std::ranges::_Find_if_fn': no matching call operator found" error at calling
ranges::find_if(network_list, [](auto const& item) { return item.IsConnected(); })

then it says something about "'std::ranges::borrowed_iterator_t': the associated constraints are not satisfied" and then "the concept 'std::ranges::range<IterableAsyncNetworkMonitor::NetworkInfo&>' evaluated to false". It's not clear what's going on.
My best guess is that find_if became stricter but I don't understand how exactly. network_list is an instance of a custom implementation of an iterable with the begin and end methods. end method returns a sentinel class. I guess that the problem is related to this because if I change the call to
ranges::find_if(network_list.begin(), network_list.end(), [](auto const& item) { return item.IsConnected(); })

I get a different error that somehow makes sense. It says that "the concept 'std::sentinel_for<IteratorAsyncSentinel,IteratorAsync>' evaluated to false" then "the concept 'std::_Weakly_equality_comparable_with<IteratorAsyncSentinel,IteratorAsync>' evaluated to false" and then "the concept 'std::_Half_equality_comparable<IteratorAsyncSentinel,IteratorAsync>' evaluated to false".
Probably my implementation of that iterable and usage of a sentinel class does not follow particular rules, but I cannot find an example how they should be implemented for functions like find_if to work. Can anybody show a correct example?
UPDATE:
Answering the question about network_list type. I thought it was enough to state that it is a custom implementation of iterable. Here it is
template<class T>
class IterableAsync final {
   friend class YieldPromise<T>;
   friend class IteratorAsync<T>;

   using handle_type = std::coroutine_handle<YieldPromise<T>>;

private:
   handle_type m_objHandle;

public:
   // promise_type is expected by STL to be publicly declared
   using promise_type = YieldPromise<T>;

private:
   explicit IterableAsync(handle_type objHandle) : m_objHandle(std::move(objHandle)) {
   }

public:
   IterableAsync(IterableAsync const& other) = delete;

   IterableAsync(IterableAsync&& other) noexcept :
      m_objHandle(other.m_objHandle) {
      other.m_objHandle = nullptr;
   }

   ~IterableAsync() {
      if(m_objHandle) {
         m_objHandle.destroy();
      }
   }

public:
   IteratorAsync<T> begin() {
      return IteratorAsync<T>(*this, false);
   }

   // ReSharper disable once CppMemberFunctionMayBeStatic
   IteratorAsyncSentinel end() {
      return IteratorAsyncSentinel();
   }

public:
   IterableAsync& operator =(IterableAsync const& other) = delete;

   IterableAsync& operator =(IterableAsync&& other) noexcept {
      m_objHandle = other.m_objHandle;
      other.m_objHandle = nullptr;
      return *this;
   }
};

UPDATE 2:
I kind of hoped that somebody would provide a link to a standard of how to properly write interable/iterator/sentinel or post that example here rather than analyzing misses in my code which might be more difficult but if that is easier, here the other requested parts
 class IteratorAsyncSentinel final {};

template<class T>
class IterableAsync;

template<class T>
class IteratorAsync final {
   friend class IterableAsync<T>;

public:
   // difference_type and value_type are expected by ranges
   using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;
   using value_type = T;

private:
   std::reference_wrapper<IterableAsync<T>> m_objIterable;
   bool m_bIsDone;

private:
   IteratorAsync(IterableAsync<T>& objIterable, bool bIsDone) :
      m_objIterable(objIterable),
      m_bIsDone(bIsDone) {
      if(!m_bIsDone) {
         Advance();
      }
   }

public:
   IteratorAsync() :
      m_objIterable(*reinterpret_cast<IterableAsync<T>*>(nullptr)),
      m_bIsDone(false) {
   }
   IteratorAsync(IteratorAsync const& other) = default;
   IteratorAsync(IteratorAsync&& other) noexcept = default;
   ~IteratorAsync() = default;

public:
   bool operator !=(IteratorAsyncSentinel const&) const {
      return !m_bIsDone;
   }

   bool operator ==(IteratorAsyncSentinel const&) const {
      return m_bIsDone;
   }

   IteratorAsync& operator ++() {
      Advance();
      return *this;
   }

   IteratorAsync operator ++(int) {
      IteratorAsync objPrevIterator = *this;
      Advance();
      return objPrevIterator;
   }

   T const& operator *() const {
      return m_objIterable.get().m_objHandle.promise().Current();
   }

private:
   void Advance() {
      m_objIterable.get().m_objHandle.resume();
      m_bIsDone = m_objIterable.get().m_objHandle.done();
   }

public:
   IteratorAsync& operator =(IteratorAsync const& other) = default;
   IteratorAsync& operator =(IteratorAsync&& other) noexcept = default;
};


What is the type of network_list? It is missing from your question and may be important to get an answer to your question.

How do you expect us to answer without providing what the definition of network_list is?

"the concept 'std::_Weakly_equality_comparable_with<IteratorAsyncSentinel,IteratorAsync>' evaluated to false" Sounds like you need comparison operators.

Your end iterator is not comparable to begin. The relevant parts of code would be your iterator and sentinel type declarations, which are missing from the question. In either case, you need revise the equality comparison operator declarations and definitions.

If you follow the chain of links from ranges::find_if via input_range you end up finding the requirements for WeaklyEqualityComparable are these.

Thank you for the hint. It turned out that sentinel type implementation now requires equality operator to be implemented. It is still a mystery why, as I mentioned a year ago it didn't require it. For me, sentinel is just a "marker" of the end of the iteration. Equality operator is definitely needed on the iterator but not on the sentinel and the need of it on the sentinel complicates things. As long as my original problem is solved, I'm posting this answer but if somebody can shed a light on these new requirements and especially on if that requirement can be removed, that'll be great.
